# Unable to Query XML file with OPENXML in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, openxml

I am trying to query a good number of XML files using SQL Server 2014. I am using the below code and I am unsure what is wrong with the syntax because nothing is being returned. My suspicion is there is something strange with the XML file.

If put in only parts of the XML text directly into the query file instead of pointing to it locally then it seems to work but I have a lot of files and really need to be able to query from a local source without manual manipulation of the files.

Example XML: https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201600349349300510_public.xml

My code:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x = R
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\USER\990\Example.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS     ReturnData(R)

SELECT @x

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleHIRS990ScheduleH/FinancialAssistanceAtCostTyp',3)  
  WITH (FinancialAssistancePolicyInd  int   '../FinancialAssistancePolicyInd',  
        FPGReferenceDiscountedCareInd int   '../FPGReferenceDiscountedCareInd',
        PersonsServedCnt int,
        NetCommunityBenefitExpnsAmt int)  

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Thanks in advance. IF there is a better way to do this then please do let me know, I am new to working with XML in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several flaws:

- FROM OPENXML is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist)
- your XML included a default namespace, which must be declared
- your XPath is wrong: `/Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleHIRS990ScheduleH/` should be `/Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleH/`

But anyway you shoudl turn to modern `XQuery`methods. Try it like this:

--This will read the XML into a declared variable.

--**attention** Your XML is declared with `utf-8`, this might lead to problems with special characters...

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x = R
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\USER\990\Example.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS ReturnData(R);
```

--This is the query, first declare the namespace(s), than use `.nodes()` and `.value()`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile'
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT ct.value('(FinancialAssistancePolicyInd)[1]','int') AS FinancialAssistancePolicyInd
      ,ct.value('(FPGReferenceDiscountedCareInd)[1]','int') AS FPGReferenceDiscountedCareInd
      ,ct.value('(FinancialAssistanceAtCostTyp/PersonsServedCnt)[1]','int') AS PersonsServedCnt
      ,ct.value('(FinancialAssistanceAtCostTyp/NetCommunityBenefitExpnsAmt)[1]','int') AS NetCommunityBenefitExpnsAmt
FROM @x.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleH') AS A(ct)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the theory and the query! Really apperciate it. I think you are right that the special characters will be a problem, the code you sent didn't work for that portion of the XML document by worked for an earlier portion which seems cleaner. (Let me know if the code should have worked anyways, I may have made a mistake.)

Do you have any suggestions how I can deal with the special characters?

Comment: @riyadude Concerning special characters: I'd suggest do read the string into a variable of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, then cut away the `<?xml ...?>` declaration and set this to a variable of type XML. Special characters need to be `NVARCHAR` (2-byte-unicode), if you don't want to get question marks as place holders... But if the XML declaration inlcudes `encoding="utf-8"` (or anything else than `utf-16`, this will not work (*cannot-switch-encoding-error*). About *Let me know if the code should have worked anyways*: This I cannot know...

Comment: Actually everything is working perfectly now. Thanks again. Haven't run into special characters issues yet but i'll check back on this post if I do. Take care!