# How do you read an XML file in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 to query XML text using  xquery. I am able to insert portions of XML text to query but I need to be able to point to a local file to read and query it and cannot figure out how to do that. Below is what I have for what I am currently doing.

```
declare @xmldata xml    
set @xmldata = '
<Orders>
  <Order OrderID="100" OrderDate="1/30/2012">
   <OrderDetail ProductID="1" Quantity="3">
    <Price>350</Price>
   </OrderDetail>
   <OrderDetail ProductID="2" Quantity="8">
    <Price>500</Price>
   </OrderDetail>
   <OrderDetail ProductID="3" Quantity="10">
    <Price>700</Price>
   </OrderDetail>
  </Order>
  <Order OrderID="200" OrderDate="2/15/2012">
   <OrderDetail ProductID="4" Quantity="5">
    <Price>120</Price>
   </OrderDetail>
  </Order>
 </Orders>'

SELECT  x.c.value('(OrderDetail)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as OrderDetail
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/Orders/Order') x(c)

--XMl File Location: "C:\Users\User\X\Example.xml")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I just answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41520723/5089204

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms191184.aspx

```
INSERT INTO T(XmlCol)  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(  
BULK 'c:\SampleFolder\SampleData3.txt',  
SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```